# RECIPIENT_SMS_AUTH_PHONE_MISSING error for SMS Authentication

Tags: docusignapi

```
< envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">
< emailSubject>API Call for adding signature request to document and sending< /emailSubject>
                < status>sent< /status>
                < documents>
                    < document>
                        < documentId>1< /documentId>
                        < name>documentName< /name> 
                    < /document> 
                < /documents>
                < recipients>
                    < signers>
                        < signer>
                        < recipientId>1< /recipientId>
                            < name>recipientName</name>
                            < email>recipientEmail</email>                  
                            < requireIdLookup>true</requireIdLookup>
                            < idCheckConfigurationName>SMS Auth $  </idCheckConfigurationName>
                            <smsAuthentication>                             
                                <senderProvidedNumbers>1234567890, 4762576577</senderProvidedNumbers>
                            </smsAuthentication>    
                            <tabs> 
                                <signHereTabs>
                                <signHere> 
                                <xPosition>100</xPosition> 
                                <yPosition>100</yPosition> 
                                <documentId>1</documentId> 
                                <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
                                </signHere>
                                </signHereTabs> 
                                <textTabs><text>
                                <anchorString>L</anchorString>
                                <documentId>1</documentId>
                                <required>true</required>
                                <shared>false</shared>
                                <width>70</width>
                                <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
                                </text></textTabs>
                            </tabs> 
                        </signer>
                    </signers> 
                </recipients>  
            </envelopeDefinition>
```

I receive "RECIPIENT_SMS_AUTH_PHONE_MISSING" error for the above. What is the problem with the above request? can someone help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can have multiple phone numbers listed in a single provider number node (you might have to create one node per node), but when I look at the restapi help page I see the following for XML format:

```
<senderProvidedNumbers xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <d6p1:string>1234567890</d6p1:string>
      </senderProvidedNumbers>
```

Try giving that a shot or breaking the numbers into two separate nodes.  I got this info from the following page:  https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/help

Comment: Cool glad to hear it worked.  Can you please accept my answer in that case?  Cheers